# Yii2 usuario queda en cache para una aplicacion diferente

Tags: yii2, cache

El titulo tal vez no explique mucho pero acá aclaro las cosas, tengo dos aplicaciones diferentes pero ambas con la misma estructura y logica para los usuarios pero en bases de datos diferentes, el problema es cuando me logeo en una de las aplicaciones si el id de ese  usuario existe en la otra aplicación se "auto-logea" en ella. La key de las cookies es diferente, pero no se que  mas debo cambiar para que no quede en cache siendo diferentes apps. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se debe a que tienes el mismo identificador para las cookies de session .
Para solucionar esto  mi primer consejo es que si has de hacer mas proyectos no copies  proyectos antiguos enteros , sino que inicializa uno desde 0 y luego si quieres vas copiando  los modelos , vistas y controladores que te hagan falta .

Para solucionar tu error has de ir a los archivos de configuración de tu aplicación yii2 , nose si tienes la basica o la avanzada :

- basica : config/web
- advanced: "frontend o backend "/ config/"maing o    main-local"

Una vez hayas encontrado tu archivo de configuración debes buscar

```
     'components' => [
     'request' => [            
                'cookieValidationKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  ],
                ...
        ]
```

> IMPORTANTE :  "xxxxxxxxxxxx "  debe ser diferente en todas tus
>   aplicaciones , y si quieres diferentes sesiones en yii2 avanzado entre
>   backend y frontend tambien deben ser diferentes